# How can I set this slide panel jQuery plugin to default close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented the panel toggle script by DojoGeekRA which is published at JqueryScript.net (demo https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Toggable-Bottom-Content-Panel-Using-jQuery-CSS/)

It functions as needed as far as the toggle open / close behavior, however it defaults to open state when the page is loaded and **I need it to default to close**.

**The JS**

```
(function($) {

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Panel.init();
    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
    Panel.togglePanel();
    });
});

var Panel = {
    isVisible : true,
    showMessage : null,
    hideMessage : null,
    animationDuration : 650,
    animationEasing : 'linear',
    init : function() {},

    hidePanel : function() {
        $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
            bottom : -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
        }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
            Panel.isVisible = false;
            Panel.updateTabMessage();
        });
    },

    showPanel : function() {
        $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
            bottom : 0
        }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
            Panel.isVisible = true;
            Panel.updateTabMessage();
        });
    },

    togglePanel : function() {
        ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
    },

    updateTabMessage : function() {
        if (this.isVisible) {
            $('.tab-controller .close').show();
            $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
        } else {
            $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
            $('.tab-controller .show').show();
        }
    },

    getAnimationOffset : function() {
        return $('.panel-content').height();
    }
}

})(jQuery);
```

#### I tried

- setting `isVisible` to `false` but nothing changes (yes I refreshed the page)
- set the `.panel-content` css rule to `display:none` and though it responds to default hidden, the JS is still in open mode so the tab states **Close** and goes off screen when clicked.

**The HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin.css?v=9">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js?v=8"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: #ddd;">

<div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="panel-controller">
        <div class="tab-controller">
            <span class="close">Close</span>
            <span class="show">Open</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="content clearfix">

        the content here

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS**

```
.panel-wrapper * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-controller {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-controller {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-controller .show {
    display: none;
}
.panel-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.panel-content .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

---

## Update

The answer from @The_Death_Raw did the task (thanks), however I needed to be able to set options dynamically and use multiple instances, so I added a  function closure and setting variable. Here is the modified working script if desired.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.bottomSlidePanel = function(options) 
{
    var wrap = this;
    
    return this.each(function() 
    {
        var setting = $.extend ({
            tab: ".tab-controller",
            contentarea: ".panel-content",
            defaultState: "close",
            animTime: 250
        }, options);
        
        $(function() {
            if( setting.defaultState === "close" ) {
                Panel.init(Panel.hidePanel(Panel.animationDuration = 0));
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    Panel.hidePanel(Panel.animationDuration = setting.animTime); 
                }, 1);
            }else{
                Panel.init();
            }
            
            $(setting.tab).on("click", function() {
                Panel.togglePanel();
            });
        });

        var Panel = {
            isVisible : true,
            showMessage : null,
            hideMessage : null,
            animationDuration : setting.animTime,
            animationEasing : "linear",
            init : function() {},

            hidePanel : function() {
                $(wrap).animate({
                    bottom : -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
                }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                    Panel.isVisible = false;
                    Panel.updateTabMessage();
                });
            },

            showPanel : function() {
                $(wrap).animate({
                    bottom : 0
                }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                    Panel.isVisible = true;
                    Panel.updateTabMessage();
                });
            },

            togglePanel : function() {
                ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
            },

            updateTabMessage : function() {
                if (this.isVisible) {
                    $(setting.tab+' .tabclose').show();
                    $(setting.tab+' .tabshow').hide();
                } else {
                    $(setting.tab+' .tabclose').hide();
                    $(setting.tab+' .tabshow').show();
                }
            },

            getAnimationOffset : function() {
                return $(setting.contentarea).height();
            }
        }
    });
}

}(jQuery));
```

#### Use

**Basic using core defaults**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // attach to the parent wrap element
  $(".panel-wrapper").bottomSlidePanel(); 
});
```

**Use options**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // attach to the parent wrap element
  $(".panel-wrapper").bottomSlidePanel({
    tab: ".tab-controller", // set tab class or ID
    contentarea: ".panel-content", // set element class or ID
    defaultState: "open", // omit to allow default close
    animTime: 500 // (int) omit to use default value
  });
});
```

If anyone has the ability to make it more efficient, please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the panel and then set AnimationDuration to 0 to hide on page load.

Wait for 1s and then set animation to 650 to make it work

```js
(function($) {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        
        Panel.init(Panel.hidePanel(Panel.animationDuration = 0));
        
        setTimeout(function(){ Panel.hidePanel(Panel.animationDuration = 650); }, 1); 
        
        $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
             Panel.togglePanel();
        });

    });

    var Panel = {

        isVisible : true,
        showMessage : null,
        hideMessage : null,
        animationDuration : 650,
        animationEasing : 'linear',

        init : function() {

        },

        hidePanel : function() {
            $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
                bottom : -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
            }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                Panel.isVisible = false;
                Panel.updateTabMessage();
            });
        },

        showPanel : function() {
            $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
                bottom : 0
            }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                Panel.isVisible = true;
                Panel.updateTabMessage();
            });
        },

        togglePanel : function() {
            ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
        },

        updateTabMessage : function() {
            if (this.isVisible) {
                $('.tab-controller .close').show();
                $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
            } else {
                $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
                $('.tab-controller .show').show();
            }
        },

        getAnimationOffset : function() {
            return $('.panel-content').height();
        }

    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.panel-wrapper * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.panel-controller {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-controller {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-controller .show {
    display: none;
}
.panel-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.panel-content .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background: #ddd;">

<div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="panel-controller">
        <div class="tab-controller">
            <span class="close">Close</span>
            <span class="show">Open</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="content clearfix">
          the content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```